# Returning moves with MiniMax

Tags: java, recursion, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I've got my code working and the program running perfectly! Turns out the problem also involved the computer not returning a 0 when required. Thank you to everyone who helped. If anyone needs any help like I did check out the code below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class TicTacToeSolver{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

            char[] board={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
            int player=1,move;

            System.out.println("Tic-Tac-Toe:");
            while (true){
                PrintBoard(board);   
                if (player==1){
                    System.out.print("Enter move: ");
                    move=input.nextInt();
                    if (ValidMove(board,move)==true){
                        board[move-1]='X';
                        player=-1;
                    }   
                }
                else{
                    board[MiniMax(board,player,0,9)[1]]='O';
                    player=1;
                }
                if(CheckWin(board)!=0){
                    PrintBoard(board);
                    System.out.println("You lost!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                else if (CheckDraw(board)==true){
                    PrintBoard(board);
                    System.out.println("Draw!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
        public static boolean ValidMove(char[]board,int move){
            if(move>=1 && move<=9){
                if (board[move-1]==0){
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        public static int CheckWin(char[] board){
            if (board[0]=='X' && board[1]=='X' && board[2]=='X'||//Horizontal.
                    board[3]=='X' && board[4]=='X' && board[5]=='X' ||
                    board[6]=='X' && board[7]=='X' && board[8]=='X' ||
                    board[0]=='X' && board[4]=='X' && board[8]=='X' ||//Diagonal.
                    board[2]=='X' && board[4]=='X' && board[6]=='X' ||
                    board[0]=='X' && board[3]=='X' && board[6]=='X' ||//Vertical.
                    board[1]=='X' && board[4]=='X' && board[7]=='X' ||
                    board[2]=='X' && board[5]=='X' && board[8]=='X'){
                return -1;
            }
            else if (board[0]=='O' && board[1]=='O' && board[2]=='O'||//Horizontal.
                    board[3]=='O' && board[4]=='O' && board[5]=='O' ||
                    board[6]=='O' && board[7]=='O' && board[8]=='O' ||
                    board[0]=='O' && board[4]=='O' && board[8]=='O' ||//Diagonal.
                    board[2]=='O' && board[4]=='O' && board[6]=='O' ||
                    board[0]=='O' && board[3]=='O' && board[6]=='O' ||//Vertical.
                    board[1]=='O' && board[4]=='O' && board[7]=='O' ||
                    board[2]=='O' && board[5]=='O' && board[8]=='O'){
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        public static boolean CheckDraw(char[] board){
            int total=0;
            for (int i=0;i<9;i++){
                if (board[i]!=0){
                    total+=1;
                }
            }
            if (total==9){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        public static void PrintBoard(char[] board){   
            System.out.println("------------------------------");
            System.out.println(board[0]+"|"+board[1]+"|"+board[2]);
            System.out.println("-+-+-");
            System.out.println(board[3]+"|"+board[4]+"|"+board[5]);
            System.out.println("-+-+-");
            System.out.println(board[6]+"|"+board[7]+"|"+board[8]); 
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
        public static int[] MiniMax(char[] board,int player,int depth, int maxDepth){
            int bestScore,bestMove=-1,score;

            if (CheckWin(board)!=0||depth==maxDepth){
                return new int[] {CheckWin(board),bestMove};
            }
            if (CheckDraw(board)==true){
                return new int[] {0,bestMove};
            }   
            if (player==-1){
                bestScore=-9999;
            }
            else{
                bestScore=9999;
            }
            for (int i=0;i<9;i++){
                if (board[i]==0){
                    if (player==-1){
                        board[i]='O';
                        score=MiniMax(board,player*-1,depth+1,maxDepth)[0];
                        board[i]=0;

                        if (score>bestScore){
                            bestScore=score;
                            bestMove=i;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        board[i]='X';
                        score=MiniMax(board,player*-1,depth+1,maxDepth)[0];
                        board[i]=0;

                        if(score<bestScore){
                            bestScore=score;
                            bestMove=i;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return new int[] {bestScore,bestMove};
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've answered this elsewhere so there must be a few of you doing this assignment! Below the first level you should only be checking if the levels below return any winning moves or not. You don't need to use any of their values. Example code:

```
public List<Location> bestMoves() {
    List<Location> winningMoves = possibleMoves().stream()
            .filter(move -> apply(move).isWinFor(nextPlayer))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    if (!winningMoves.isEmpty())
        return winningMoves;
    else
        return possibleMoves().stream()
                .filter(move -> apply(move).bestMoves().isEmpty())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could return both the move and the score through an object that contains both.

```
public class TicTacToeSolver{
    private static class Move {
        int move;
        int score;
        Move( int m, int s ) {
           move = m;
           score = s;
        }
    }
    ...
 }
```

You could return this object like this:

```
 return new Move( bestScore, bestMove );
```

Within minimax() itself, you could get the score like this:

```
Move candidateMove = MiniMax(board,player*-1,depth+1,maxDepth);
int score = candidateMove.score;
```

At the top level, you could get the best move like this:

```
 Move bestMove = MiniMax(board,player,0,9);
 int move = bestMove.move;
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to try to help me out. I believe I implemented your advice correctly and I definitely do see some big improvements with decision making but it still has major flaws. If you could take another look at the updated code that would be awesome.

Comment: @ReconMa - I see this is your first question. Welcome to stackoverflow. Be sure to scan through the brief introduction at http://stackoverflow.com/tour. You can ask specific questions and vote for the answers that help. Please specify the "major flaws," and consider whether those are a separate question.